# Группировка и соединение строк в DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

В общем, хочу написать метод, который на вход принимает:
`DataTable`(заранее неизвестная структура),`String[]`, где содержатся колонки по которым нужно сделать группировку, Делитель.

Задача в том, что бы выполнить группировку по полям, которые перечислены в массиве, далее внутри каждой группы сделать объединение строк, через делитель.

Т.е дана такая таблица:

> Grp Val1 Val2
>
> 1   ; v1 ; d1
>
> 1  ;  v2 ; d2
>
> 1   ; v3 ; d3
>
> 2   ; v1  ;d1
>
> 2  ;  v2;  d2
>
> 2  ;  v3 ; d3

На выходе получится 2 строки:

> 1 ;v1 | v2 | v3; d1 | d2| d3
>
> 2 ;v1 | v2 | v3; d1 | d2| d3

При помощи циклов я представляю, как это сделать. Но можно ли это сделать LINQ запросом?

**UPD**

Ну и вкратце ответ на вопрос "Почему именно DataTable?"

DataTable берется, как результат парсинга Excel, структура которых заранее неизвестна.

Мой выбор пал на DataTable именно из-за возможности на ходу конструировать таблицу.

Comment: А зачем работать с нетипизированной DataTable и названиями свойств? Не лучше ли считать данные в коллекцию типизированных объектов?

Comment: @VladD, заранее неизвестная структура.

Comment: А _почему_ она заранее не известна? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: @VladD, данные тянутся из Excel. Какие поля тянуть описывается в конфигурационном файле. Эти данные я засовываю в DataTable, а дальше должен сгруппировать, как я описал в вопросе

Comment: @VladD, есть какие-то альтернативы? DataTable взял именно из-за его динамичности.

Comment: Я никогда не работал с DataTable, так что я бы наверное либо сгенерировал класс в рантайме, либо использовал `List<Dictionary<name, value>>`. Поэтому не могу ничего посоветовать. Подождём, пока придёт кто-нибудь с опытом.

Comment: @VladD, а с использованием List<Dictionary<name, value>> . Как выглядело бы решение? Я думаю, что с DataTable не сильно отличаться будет.

Comment: @VladD создал вопрос отдельный для вас https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803986/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0 , где вы можете описать один из своих подходов при работе с заранее неизвестными структурами.

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение для `List<Dictionary<name, value>>`. Возможно, оно обобщается до решения для `DataTable`:

Для начала, нам нужен класс, который сравнивает последовательности объектов поэлементно:

```
class SequenceComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<object>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<object> x, List<object> y) =>
        x.Zip(y, (o1, o2) => o1.Equals(o2)).All(v => v);
    public int GetHashCode(List<object> list) =>
        list.Aggregate(0, (v, obj) => v ^ obj.GetHashCode());
}
```

Имея такой класс, сравнение тривиально. В качестве ключа мы выбираем нужные значения, и используем только что определённый компаратор.

```
var data = new[]
{
    new Dictionary<string, object>()
        { ["Name"] = "Вася", ["Age"] = 25, ["JobTitle"] = "Программист" },
    new Dictionary<string, object>()
        { ["Name"] = "Вася", ["Age"] = 22, ["JobTitle"] = "Программист" },
    new Dictionary<string, object>()
        { ["Name"] = "Федя", ["Age"] = 54, ["JobTitle"] = "Директор" },
    new Dictionary<string, object>()
        { ["Name"] = "Аделаида", ["Age"] = 20, ["JobTitle"] = "Муза" },
    new Dictionary<string, object>()
        { ["Name"] = "Федя", ["Age"] = 2, ["JobTitle"] = "Хомячок" },
};

var columns = new[] { "Name", "JobTitle" };
var groups = data.GroupBy(entity => SelectValues(entity, columns), new SequenceComparer());
```

Получаем 4 группы.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде сделал, но что-то не так изящно получилось, как хотелось=(

```
var newDt = dt.Clone();
        var columns = new[] { "F1" ,"F2"};
        var res = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => KeySelector(x, columns), (key, rows) => ResultSelector(rows, columns, newDt, " | "), new SequenceComparer());

    static List<object> KeySelector(DataRow row, string[] columns)
    {
        var listObjcets = new List<object>();
        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            listObjcets.Add(row[column]);
        }
        return listObjcets;
    }

    class SequenceComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<object>>
    {
        public bool Equals(List<object> x, List<object> y) =>
            x.Zip(y, (o1, o2) => o1.Equals(o2)).All(v => v);
        public int GetHashCode(List<object> list) =>
            list.Aggregate(0, (v, obj) => v ^ obj.GetHashCode());
    }

    static DataRow ResultSelector(IEnumerable<DataRow> rows, string[] columns, DataTable dt, string separator)
    {
        var newRow = dt.NewRow();
        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
        {
            for (var index = 0; index < row.ItemArray.Length; index++)
            {
                var item = row.ItemArray[index];
                if (columns.Contains(dt.Columns[index].ColumnName))
                {
                    newRow[index] = item;
                }
                else
                {
                    newRow[index] += DBNull.Value.Equals(newRow[index]) ? item.ToString() : separator + item;
                }
            }
        }
        return newRow;
    }
```

Comment: Что-то мне не нравится `KeySelector`. А что, если в значении встретится плюс?

Comment: @VladD, так вроде, все равно будет уникальная группа. "val++"

Comment: А если одно значение будет "1+2", а второе "3"? У вас выйдет "1+2+3".

Comment: @VladD, сделал "по взрослому", взяв SequenceComparer из вашего ответа. По идее, сейчас никаких проблем не должно быть.