# Способы работы с данными структура которых заранее неизвестна

Tags: c#, .net

Предположим, программа должна читать Excel структура которой на этапе компиляции неизвестна, а затем выполнить какую-нибудь подобную [штуку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803876/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-datatable).

Я решил задачу хранения неизвестных заранее данных через DataTable. Однако, быть может есть еще более удачные решения?

Comment: Чудес не бывает: код делает только то, что вы зашили в код. Либо ваш код знает  жёстко заданную структуру, либо вы договариваетесь о конвенциях, вписываете в код конвенциальные правила и в пределах конвенций можете что угодно прописывать. Вот есть же конвенции в Code First - и пока вы в рамках конвенций - пишите код как хотите.

Comment: Зависит от задачи и исходных данных. В Excel тоже можно наворотить так, что парсинг обычного текста покажется идеальным вариантом. В любом случае задача определяет необходимый набор данных, и его структура известна. А способов выбрать нужные данные из исходного, пусть и не структурированного набора очень много. Вам удобно использовать решение с DataTable? - отлично, используйте DataTable.